# Kotlin рефакторинг кода

Tags: android, kotlin

Имеются похожие методы, например

```
suspend fun getProfile() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val settings = settingsDao.get
        netManager.isConnectedToInternet?.let{ connect ->
            if(connect){
                RemoteDataSource(settings.token).getProfile()
            } else{
                NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
            }
        } ?: NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
        request
    }

suspend fun getFilter() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val settings = settingsDao.get
        val request = netManager.isConnectedToInternet?.let{
            if(it){
                RemoteDataSource(settings.token).getFilter()
            } else{
                NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
            }
        } ?: NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
        request
    }
```

У них все одинаково, кроме одной строчки, я хочу это отредактировать

```
suspend fun getResult(networkCall : () -> NewRequestModel<Any>) = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        netManager.isConnectedToInternet?.let { connect ->
            if (connect) {
                networkCall.invoke()
            } else {
                NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
            }
        } ?: NewRequestModel.ErrorInternet(true)
    }
```

Как вызывать:

```
suspend fun getFilter() = withContext(Dispatchers.IO){
        val settings = settingsDao.get
        val result = getResult{RemoteDataSource().getFilter()}
    }
```

Как можно перенести `val settings = settingsDao.get` в `getResult`, передав в `networkCall.invoke()` `setting.token`?

Comment: По идее вы networkCall где-то до вызова getResult создаёте через RemoteDataSource. Коли так, то при создании последнего вам и надо засетить в него токен. И тогда вам не надо передавать токен в getResult

Comment: А в чем проблема networkCall определить с параметром, раз суть его у всех вызовов одинакова?